# Android Studio UI breaking constantly

Tags: android, android-studio

### The problem

I've been using Android Studio for quite a while, but I've been facing some random GUI bugs on it since the major update to version 3.0 I believe.

The buttons on the editor disappear, code completion stops working, context menu doesn't show up, and so on. Apparently this is happening at random.

But now, on version 3.2.1 it seems to be happening more often.

To illustrate what I mean, check the image below:

[image: Broken UI 1]

I wasn't able to pinpoint what might be causing this, but it has been a real pain to develop on it ever since.

**Edit:** The only clue I found so far is that it seems to happen more often once the code completion starts to drag a little, or stops working altogether (No more suggestions on screen). Almost every time this starts to happen, the GUI is almost certain to break next.

Here's another screenshot showing the broken UI right after I used the code suggestion to complete a line on one of my XML layout files:

[image: Broken UI 2]

And once the GUI breaks, other parts of AS stop working as well, such as the Context Menu, or even the top menu (File, Edit, View, Navigate, Code, Analyze, ..., Help).

[image: Broken context menu]

### What I've tried so far

I've tried to clear all caches, reinstall it, use it on a different machine, work with different projects, neither of those things worked.

I also tried to change the amount of memory that AS is using, but that also didn't help.

Closing AS and opening it back again solves to issue for a time, but after a matter of minutes is starts to break again.

I've also [opened an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122015591) on AS issue tracker.

### My setup

- Android Studio 3.2.1
- Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on
  October 8, 2018
- JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Windows 10 10.0

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .AndroidStudio folder?

Comment: I have. I’ve also reinstalled it.